# Unable to find if a node exists in realtime database

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I have a firebase realtime tree which has a particular node  `New Ride` set when the user is online, when offline the node `New Ride` gets removed. This works ok for the first time, When the user tries to go online again I can't set up the node.  I want to check if the node already exists in the tree if not add it.

This is my code so far

```
DatabaseReference rideRequestRef = FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL: firebaseUrl)
    .reference()
    .child("Drivers")
    .child(currentFirebaseUser.uid)
    .child("New Ride");
var ref = FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL: firebaseUrl)
        .reference()
        .child("Drivers")
        .child(currentFirebaseUser.uid);

    await ref
        //.child(currentFirebaseUser.uid)
        .child("New Ride")
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      if (dataSnapshot == null) {
       
        rideRequestRef.set("searching");
      } else {
        rideRequestRef.set("searching");
       
      }
    });
   
    rideRequestRef.onValue.listen((event) {});
  }
```

Comment: You're overcomplicating the solution. Why remove the Node? Instead, override it; it will be simpler and less costly.

Have a node for new_ride_status that you set to searching or the inverse, check that for the status, and with `set` override any other details if the status changes.

A listener can then be attached to status and it won't have to be re-instated each time the node gets removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your code here:

```
await ref
    //.child(currentFirebaseUser.uid)
    .child("New Ride")
    .once()
    .then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  if (dataSnapshot == null) {       
    rideRequestRef.set("searching");
  } else {
    rideRequestRef.set("searching");       
  }
});
```

It seems that whether the node exists or not makes no difference on what you do. So why not replace this entire fragment with this?

```
rideRequestRef.set("searching");
```